# gzuncompress returns data error

Tags: base64, corruption, gzip

I am using the gzcompress and gzuncompress to send over base64_encoded data (an array) over a url. Below is the sample code, on some servers I get a data error and on some everything runs smoothly. What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing something which is causing data corruption occasionally?

```
$str='eNqFVduSoyAQ_RfnBxTxxj6mKq_7CZaJRK0xklEy2Zmp_fcFFRFo3PgSOKf7dJ8WrEhWkJ-JRDEJHmN3r8av8sp6Nga_JpKR4O2KoyjP5CrKNYXTP9zk3eafXFwJWs8aVnL2kEtEApTO8QkJWlrVdCwvjQ4OSeCiQqWhO1TkHKrP8sYGLpcpCX5Pr6qvVaQCyxftmnbmiIZwGMp_xYL7y5Xo1H3TtdxoKTdbgedlaXfPQDMDaQZcXJmo4cLqL6NfU11S7lU3_Ieisti-oNDCypE-aMX3xuKVMjeh6lRguoJe86S7OtyZmpHcdUgF993w7gZnqng2yrnbOEIrTnt6pwOfDJOE8tv5fDYSTW1Vs5fJOZ1ORqct-wS0RIY28kwRbxjoUD7DxvBwJh-dd2cMytU2coaBt12vEDoSQoYQUtsxKBQfC8VHQrEx6q0jDArhYyF8JITdcym3E1AoORZKjoQSQwir7RQUSo-F0iOhFDglXCJcJ-94T91LXDDLx-HYt4B8txcQPqTyFD45ZwN48WYbCkcXOho-p1G0MWy3cgOBL5jU1Ff27OV7dn3_eDJOoQZQZDDgJvLl69INjb9LRfCXKrLc2Hi_dbSvwVKQQfBcXGvhnjSLQdeqSbH6teLBYguHZlubSIbwzPtB1qjzyhUa9bwV2caAHU9N3D0WOgH8-bASXDDv3gp7PUKxTuE_P8tUbZZtZmaR7KlhXDAHivr7DzuC_e4%2C';
print_r(unserialize(gzuncompress(stripslashes(base64_decode(strtr($str, '-_,', '+/='))))));
```

Comment: We have no idea why you're using `strtr` or `stripslashes`. But you're likely to find it a lot easier to debug if you perform one operation at a time...

Comment: I got this code from the php manual itself (look in the comments) http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php. I tried adding the urlencode around the $str but still no success. I will take your suggestion and break it into multiple lines thanks.

Comment: Just because someone's left it in a comment in a manual doesn't make it appropriate. In particular, have you performed the same *encoding* step which is in the comments as well, on the sending side?

Comment: Yes the encoding step is fine as in the comments. Please note the question again, it works on some servers correctly and in some it does not, I have tested it many times xyz.com/abc.php?str='ASCsse34S...' and one localhost:8888/abc.php?str='ASCsse34S...' it worked fine on localhost and couple of my servers but in three other cases it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this. Instead of encoding a serialized array then compressing it, I straightaway went for passing the array via GET and urlencode. It worked flawlessly.